# Formatting a column as a date for every worksheet in workbook (excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get an excel column which is currently formatted as general to show as a date using vba. I've seen several posts on here about this and tried a few different methods, but everything I try returns an error saying "Cannot set NumberFormat of Range class". Here's my current code:

```
For i = 2 To 13
        Sheets(i).Select
        Columns(14).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" //This line seems to be causing issues
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 65
        Range("A1:Q1").Select
    Next
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
'Columns("N:N").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

For i = 2 To 13
        Sheets(i).Select
        Columns("N:N").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 65
        Range("A1:Q1").Select
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

ZAT's answer will fix your error but please god don't use `Select` for your own sake.

- It slows down your macros by forcing the screen to update.
- It's not explicit.

Following this pattern will improve your code.

```
For i = 2 To 13
   With Worksheets(i)
      .Columns("N:N").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
      ' etc
   End With
Next i
```

Also, `Worksheets` excludes Charts.

Comment: Neither of these answers seems to be working for me. Is it possible the header in (1,N) is messing this up? There's a header on the sheet that says date of test. Is it possible to adjust the range so that it gets only (2,N) and beyond?

Comment: Having a cell in a range that cannot translate to a format should not throw an error.  Are some of the cells locked or protected?

Comment: Also you can use `.Range("N2:N" & .Rows.Count)`.